# Load different view on first run

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I'm programming an app at the moment which requires on the first run for the app toload a different view in which the user can select its prefered settings.Here's the code

implementation **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:             (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

// Determining Storyboard identifier for first view
// Determining Storyboard identifier for first view
NSString *storyboardID = [self hasEverBeenLaunched]? @"MainView" : @"LoginView";
// Setting proper view as a rootViewController
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"view45"] ;
```

It then goes on with the following code:

```
- (BOOL)hasEverBeenLaunched
{
// A boolean which determines if app has eer been launched
BOOL hasBeenLaunched;

// Testig if application has launched before and if it has to show the home-login screen        to login
// to social networks (facebook, Twitter)
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasAlreadyLaunched"]) {
// Setting variable to YES because app has been launched before
hasBeenLaunched = YES;
 NSLog(@"App has been already launched");
} else {
// Setting variable to NO because app hasn't been launched before
hasBeenLaunched = NO;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasAlreadyLaunched"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 NSLog(@"This is the first run ever...");
}

return hasBeenLaunched;
}
```

Just a few quick notes: View 45 is the initial starting up view which should only show once, Otherwise the main view controller is ticked under atrributes to be the initial view controller(The one that always loads up at the start, after the first run)

So the problem is that it only ever loads view 45 ,the first run view, but whats causing that exactly ?

Comment: Bumping your question after 12 minutes? Really?!?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the following line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"view45"] ;
```

It is ignoring the value of `storyboardID` and just using the string `@"view45"`, so that's why you'll always get the same one every single time.

If you want to fix it, change it to the following line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
```

You can see that now it is making use of the value in storyboardID.

Comment: What should I do then ?

Comment: I edited my answer to state how the code should be changed to take it into account.

Comment: Updated code:  ' // Determining Storyboard identifier for first view
    // Determining Storyboard identifier for first view
    NSString *storyboardID = [self hasEverBeenLaunched]? @"main1" : @"view45";
    // Setting proper view as a rootViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID] ; '   main1 is the normal view where as view45 is the initial view. It now appears with the sprinboard error -3, so what should i do ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is happening in the simulator. Try uninstalling the app from the simulator, closing the simulator and re-running the app. Otherwise try on a real device.